# How to get a single string (a pandoc citation) from list of strings (citation keys)

Tags: r, string, pandoc

I'm working with a list object consisting of a variable number of citation keys.

```
mylist <- structure(list(steele1998pulsus = "steele1998pulsus", wright1997evaluation = "wright1997evaluation", wright1996continuous = "wright1996continuous"), .Names = c("steele1998pulsus", "wright1997evaluation", "wright1996continuous")) 

paste0("@", unlist(mylist))
```

generates:

```
[1] "@steele1998pulsus"     "@wright1997evaluation" "@wright1996continuous"
```

I've tried various combinations of cat() and paste() without success - my goal is a text string formatted as below (a pandoc citation of multiple keys).

```
[@steele1998pulsus; @wright1997evaluation; @wright1996continuous]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not great with R's string-processing commands (I find it very hard to remember the difference between `collapse` and `sep`) but I can do it like this:

```
paste("[", paste(paste0("@", mylist), collapse="; "), "]", sep="")
```

Producing the desired output:

```
> paste("[", paste(paste0("@", mylist), collapse="; "), "]", sep="")
[1] "[@steele1998pulsus; @wright1997evaluation; @wright1996continuous]"
```

Also, because we don't need the `sep` argument for any of the steps we
can just use `paste0` for all of them:

```
paste0("[", paste0(paste0("@", mylist), collapse="; "), "]")
```

Comment: or `sprintf('[@%s]', paste0(unlist(mylist), collapse = '; @'))`, FYI `paste0` is short for `paste(..., sep = '')`

Comment: If you have three separate items and they all get supplied to `paste` "sep-arately" as it were, you get one item linked by `sep`. If you have one object Say a character vector or list with three items, you get three items unless you use `collapse`. The `paste` functions behave very much like `mapply`.